# Java: How do I make an array and fill it with objects in my constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, playing-cards

I am trying to create a constructor that creates an array and fills that array with custom objects. This array would represent a deck of cards.

```
public class DeckOfCards {
public static Card[] deck = new Card[52];

//constructor
DeckOfCards(){
    Card[] deck = new Card[52];

    deck[0]=new Card("Ace","Clubs"); deck[1]=new Card("Two","Clubs"); 
    deck[2]=new Card("Three","Clubs");..(ect)...deck[49]=new 
    Card("Jack","Diamonds");
    deck[50]=new Card("Queen","Diamonds"); deck[51]=new Card("King","Diamonds");
}
```

I feel like this constructor should create an array and fill it with card objects but it doesn't recognize any objects instantiated from DeckOfCards() as arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring the deck again inside your constructor. I would initialize the deck this way. Iterating through two arrays, simplest one.

```
DeckOfCards(){
    
    suit = ['Hearts','Diamonds','Clubs','Spades'];
    number=['Ace','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King'];
    
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<13;j++){
            deck[i+j]=new Card(number[j],suit[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an scope problem since you are declaring again

```
Card[] deck = new Card[52];
```

inside the constructor, leaving without effect the global member, do instead use the deck object.... (by the way, no need for static objects...)

```
DeckOfCards(){

    deck[0]=new Card("Ace","Clubs"); deck[1]=new Card("Two","Clubs"); 
    deck[2]=new Card("Three","Clubs");..(ect.).deck[49]=new 
    Card("Jack","Diamonds");
    deck[50]=new Card("Queen","Diamonds"); deck[51]=new Card("King","Diamonds");
}
```

Comment: How would I then instantiate the deck array? I want an array of Card objects to be made and filled up every time I instantiate a DeckOfCards object.

Comment: save the card values in two arrays and loop them in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to initialise `deck` again in the constructor. Just use the class-level variable you defined.

Second, `deck` should not be `static`, so remove that word.

Third, make the constructor public.

And last but not least, you should probably initialise the deck in a smarter way.

```
public class DeckOfCards {
    public Card[] deck = new Card[52];

    //constructor
    public DeckOfCards(){
        String[] numbers = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
        String[] suits = { "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts" };
        int i = 0;
        for (String suit: suits) {
            for (String number: numbers) {
                deck[i] = new Card(number, suit);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete that line and it will be fine :
Card[] deck = new Card[52];